# Separability of subspaces of homogeneous topological spaces

Tags: gn.general-topology, homogeneous-spaces

Let $\ X\ $ be a homogenous separable topological space (i.e. for every $\ x\ y\in X\ $ there exists a homeomorphism $\ f:X\to X\ $ such that $\ f(x)=y,\ $ and there is a countable dense subset of $\ X).\ $

**Question**  Is every subspace of $\ X\ $ separable?

The question allows several variations by considering different stronger kinds of homogeneity. The other direction would be to consider different separability properties like Hausdorff, normal, etc. (*No, forget the metric case* :) ).

I would conjecture that in the simple case of homogeneity there should be an example of $\ X,\ $ and of its subspace $\ Y\ $ which is not separable while $\ X\ $ is.

Answer (score 8):

This fails even for topological groups.  For example, the separable topological group $\mathbb{Z}^{\mathfrak{c}}$ contains a subgroup of uncountable cellularity (hence certainly not separable!).  This is a result of my colleague Vladimir Uspenskij in the paper below:

*Uspenskij, V. V.*, [**On the Suslin number of subgroups of products of countable groups**](https://eudml.org/doc/196773), Acta Univ. Carol., Math. Phys. 36, No. 2, 85-87 (1995). [ZBL0854.20064](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:0854.20064).

Comment: Be warned that I am not an expert on topological groups, even though I have heard many talks on them!

Comment: The homogeneous compact space $\{0, 1\}^{\frak c}$ is separable but contains the non-separable $\Sigma$-product with any base point.

Comment: That the subgroup $\mathbb{Z}^{(\mathfrak{c})}$ of finitely supported elements is not separable is immediate.

Comment: Todd, thank you for your answer. (I've upvoted it, and now I wait patiently or less patiently for more answers). Only after seeing your answer I recalled the Szpilrajn-Marczewski's theorem about the separability of the product of continuum of separable spaces. A generalization of this theorem for general cardinals (and arbitrary "separability") must be known, I am sure (it's also in my old UW script on topology for 2nd-year students).

Answer (score 3):

Any compact homogeneous hereditarily separable space has size at most $\mathfrak{c}$ (this is a result of Ismail). Thus any compact homogeneous separable space of bigger size provides a counterexample (e.g. $2^\mathfrak{c}$ as in Anonymous' comment).

Answer (score 2):

There are Banach spaces $X$ for which the dual space $X^*$ is separable in the weak* topology yet the unit ball $B_{X^*}$ of $X^*$ is not. A notable example is $X=J\!L_2$, the [Johnson](https://mathoverflow.net/users/2554/bill-johnson)–Lindenstrauss space.

> W.B. Johnson, and J. Lindenstrauss, Some remarks on weakly compactly generated Banach spaces, *Israel J. Math.* **17** (1974), 219–230. Correction ibid **32**
>   No. 4 (1979), 382–383.

Comment: Tomek, is the said unit ball not separable under the topology induced by the weak* topology of $X^*$?

Comment: I trust you. :)

Comment: @WlodAA, yes, the ball is not weak*-separable as $JL_2$ does not embed into $\ell_\infty$.